# Use of <is depended on>

Tags: sentence-construction, verb-usage

Is the use of **'is depended on'** in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

[image: "As is revealed in Eq. 16, the axial velocity is depended on the value of M_cri."]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence should state

> As is revealed in Eq. 16, the axial velocity **is dependent** on the value of *M*<sub>*cri*</sub>.

Confusing *dependent* with *depended* is a common auditory mistake. Only use *depended on* when talking about trust/expectation:

> Her son is **depended on** to make his bed every morning.
>
> The cash register is **depended on** for the business to survive.

Comment: It also could be confused with *depends on*. "the axial velocity *depends* on the value". Or plain *depended* (as past tense) "the axial velocity *depended* on the value"

Comment: @user3169 Possible, but judging that the sentence seems like a therefore statement for an equation, I think that's unlikely.